# Unable to connect to gmail via Gmail API. How can we turn on Less secure app access?

Tags: java, gmail

I am connecting to the gmail account to verify the confirmation emails sent by our application. When implementing it originally, in order to connect to gmail successfully, we had to set the account with 'Less secure app access' configuration to ON.

Looks like google turned that setting to off now from May 30,2022 and so the authentication is failing now.

How can I connect to Gmail account to verify the confirmation emails now?

java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)

Comment: Generate [separate credentials](https://www.lifewire.com/get-a-password-to-access-gmail-by-pop-imap-2-1171882) for your app

Comment: @g00se are you sure that apps password after the removal of less secure apps?  Have you tested it?

Comment: To be fair, it was with non-Java apps. They were possibly using oauth2

Answer (score 2):

You could try authentification via "App password".

On your Google account:

1. set "2-Step Verification" ON
   [2-Step Verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as6O9.png)
2. create 16-character "App password"(
   [How to create app password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en)) -> result should be similar to:
   [16-character "App password"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as6O9.png)
3. Instead of Google account password use 16-character password

   ```
   MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
   foreach (string receiver in DolociPrejemnike())
       mail.To.Add(receiver);
   mail.From = new MailAddress("app_gmail@gmail.com", "No replay"); //pošiljatelj (vedno enak)
   mail.Subject = SetSubject();
   mail.Body = SetBody();
   mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

   SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
   smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
   smtp.Port = 587;
   smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
   smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("app_gmail@gmail.com", "xtqapucsmyvqmvxp"); // Enter seders User name and password  
   smtp.EnableSsl = true;
   smtp.Send(mail);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an apps password and use that in place of your standard google password  [How to create a Apps Password for connecting to Google's SMTP server.](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/IGOt3zo98Xw)

Or

You will need to enable [xoauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol) in your code or if you have a workspace account go though the gmail api using a service account.

[OAuth2 Support](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2)

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true"); // required for Gmail
props.put("mail.imap.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
Store store = session.getStore("imap");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", username, oauth2_access_token);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also fighting with this for some time. When I started to use an app password it fails with the same exception as it was mentioned in the question.
After several attempts I logged in to my mail box in a browser and it asked me to authenticate again saying "There was some strange activity observed". Unexpectedly after this browser login the same piece of code started to work correctly authenticating successfully.